# Make input Textbox as currency format (WPF MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i am new in WPF, just start learning today. can anyone help me how to format the TextBox as currency format? which in my Textbox, can only be inputted by the numbers with 2 decimal point?
Thanks.

Comment: Nope not difficult at all. But it is noted the person asking the question felt so welcome in this forum they left again.

Answer (score 14):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Txt, StringFormat=C}"/>
```

Comment: This will display the currency sign depending on user system setting, which does not have to correspond with currency in database.

Comment: or whatever datasource you have :) . Your solution is definetely cleaner than the mine (vote up), but has a shortcomming that you have no control which currency sign is displayed to user and thus does not have to correspond with data.

Comment: no, you are just right, my solution is the smallest answer but not really useful in real world :-). I didn't wrote a more detailed answer because the question is asked than open that there are thousands of possible solutions...

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this

```
 <TextBox TextAlignment="Right"
      Text="{Binding Price,
           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
           StringFormat='#.00',
           ConverterCulture={x:Static sysglb:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"/>
```

which forces the text to have right alignment and to have a format like 105.00 or 19.95 with decimal point/comma depending on user system settings. You can also add a currency sign to string format if applicable.

Edit: Sorry, I am spoiled with automatic importing of namespaces. In your top-level element (Usercontrol, Window, ...) add:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
     ...
     xmlns:sysglb="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
     ...
>
```

Comment: thanks for help, i try this code, but why i can't use  sysglb:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture} *sorry for my stupid question >.<

Comment: If you don't use ReSharper plugin (Hey! It's worth the money! Ok, I am biased, because I use other products of that company...), the namespaces are not imported automatically. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @user2473454 I get the same...